# Do search engines add weight for microformats?

Tags: seo, microformats, html, rel

For example, if I had

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">My friend Bill</a>
```

*or*

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" rel="friend">My friend Bill</a>
```

Will Google for example give extra weight to the second because I specified they are a friend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to their webmaster documentation microformats may be used to display additional information in the search results but don't affect the page rank.

http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99170